# PHP error when trying to set html element to google trends embed

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, google-trends

I am getting an error when trying to set the html property of an element with jquery to google trends embed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titlw</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hide" id="google_trends"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
</script>
</html>
<?php

echo "
<script>
    $('#google_trends').removeClass('hide');
    $('#google_trends').html('<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2213_RC01/embed_loader.js\"></script> <script type=\"text/javascript\"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget(\"TIMESERIES\", {\"comparisonItem\":[{\"keyword\":\"a\",\"geo\":\"\",\"time\":\"today 5-y\"}],\"category\":0,\"property\":\"froogle\"}, {\"exploreQuery\":\"date=today%205-y&gprop=froogle&q='a'\",\"guestPath\":\"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/\"});</script>');
</script>";


?>
```

**Error message** -

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: Why even involve PHP in this? (That error also reads like a developer console error, not PHP/server side)

Comment: Why are you doing this? Surely you can simply add the script to the html. Why use JQuery? And why is PHP being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not need to print the output using **echo** function.It will embed itself within the specified div. Here the div id is *google_trends*
2. Your requirement to show/hide *google_trends* div will be fulfilled by initializing jquery using *ready* function. Once the page loads, it will remove
   *hide* class and show google trend request results.
3. Use **renderExploreWidgetTo** function
   than **renderExploreWidget**.With this, you can define your div id in which you want to display your output.

Try the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titlw</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hide" id="google_trends"></div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/1328_RC04/embed_loader.js"> </script>
 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#google_trends').removeClass('hide');
    trends.embed.renderExploreWidgetTo(google_trends,'TIMESERIES', {'comparisonItem':[{'keyword':'a','geo':'','time':'today 5-y'}],'category':0,'property':'froogle'}, {'exploreQuery':'date=today%205-y&gprop=froogle&q=a','guestPath':'https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/'});

});

</script>
```

Note: This is a standalone code as I have added jquery CDN link and google trend's ember_loader js file.